# Show IOS Device Screen on Mac OS 10.9.5 Mavericks while presentation to others in remote sharing session

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

Can anyone provide information about utility regarding the IOS device (iPhone 6 OS 8.1) screen show on Mac OS 10.9.5 machine for presentation purpose.

I came across through my research , MAC OS 10.10 Yosemite with Quick Time Player with IOS 8 , can able to show screen on Mac machine. This is unique machine in OS 10.10 , 
' 
My Appium configuration and suite setup in OS 10.9.5 , So I wanted to show IOS Device execution during presentation remotely.

I appreciate your support / thoughts in this with regards to OS 10.9.5

Answer (score 0):

Try using Reflector 2 by Air Squirrels.

http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/

It costs $15, and allows you to connect from the iPhone device to your Mac via AirPlay.

At least with my setup, there was latency and animations looked choppy.  Which is why I usually go with a lightning VGA adapter for projectors, or the lightning cable + Quicktime to sling the screen to a laptop.  But with your setup, something like Reflector2 might be the way to go.